# Return an object typed to keys of an input object (typescript)

Tags: typescript

Im trying to return a typed object from a function. I need object properties to match the input object which implements a basic interface:

```
export interface LocationMap {
  [displayKey: string]: string[];
}
```

such that the object returned match. For example:

```
const foobar: LocationMap = {
  foo: ['bar', 'baz']
}

//function I'm trying to implement:
function bar(map: LocationMap) {
  //do something...

  return {
    foo: ['foobar']
  }
}
```

How do I ensure that when passed a `LocationMap` with a property `foo` that an object with the same shape will be returned?

Comment: not sure what you are asking...

Comment: I think he wants a way for the typescript ensure that what is passed as parameter to a function an object with the same keys is returned

Comment: If that's the case @nossonh, why don't you specify that the bar function returns a LocationMap?

Comment: @DerickFelix I need to ensure that it's a LocationMap with the same keys. windowsill's  answer is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is only with the type system, then tell typescript that your function returns the same type of thing that is inputed.

```
export interface LocationMap {
  [K: string]: string[];
}

interface LocationMapFoo extends LocationMap {
  foo: string[];
}

const foobar: LocationMapFoo = {
  foo: ['bar', 'baz']
}

function bar<T extends LocationMap>(map: T): T {
  return map;
}

const gg = bar(foobar);
const rr = gg.foo; // No type error
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was trying to do. I also found the typescript implementation of Object.entries helpful, it does a similar idea